# Slide nav bar from the left in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to slide the nav bar from left. Presently, it is sliding from top. I tried this:

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/14779/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="background:#f8f8f9;">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Static navbar -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" id="collbtn" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeadCollapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    
            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    
          </div>
    
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav allCaps navbar-collapse collapse navHeadCollapse navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a>Contact</a></li>
          <li><a>Help</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

I have seen posts on this but they don't work for me.

Comment: I don't see what you've tried to get it to slide left.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

html

```
<nav>

<div id="sidebar">

  <h1>Your nav here</h1>


    <div id="sidebar-btn">
      <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#sidebar > h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -13px;    
}
#sidebar > h5 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}
#sidebar-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -60px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}

#sidebar {
  background: #000000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  top: 0;
  transition: left 0.3s linear;
}
#sidebar > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar > ul {
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -14px;
}
#sidebar.visible {
  left: 0;
  transition: left 0.3s linear;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('#sidebar-btn').click(function() {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visible');
});
// Operator
  $('#operator').click(function() {
    $('#operator_show').fadeIn('slow');
  });
  $('.close').click(function() {
    $('#operator_show').fadeOut('slow');
  });
```

added a jsfiddle to it

https://jsfiddle.net/Cyrus_Zei/wznwyc2u/

Comment: thanks for reply. I have these samples. But I am not able to apply this for above code.

Comment: You want to have the links or the whole navbar ? Since I have made it so that you can replace the "your nav here" and add all your links